# Applied - how to represent confidence (failure probability) in geometric progression of computer upgrades

Tags: probability, statistics, confidence-interval

I think there is a correct way of representing confidence in the below table, but I was never strong at statics. This is based on a practical problem.

In reality, the "upgrade" has gone through a number of QA tests, and in fact should not cause any breakages. In practice an upgrade sometimes causes failures. What I want to do is minimise the impact of such a failure.

- I have 1000 computers.
- I want to upgrade these computers with an identical upgrade.
- There is an unknown chance that this upgrade will break a computer.
- I want to do it efficiently (in as few rounds as possible).
- I want to define my confidence in each round of the likelihood that a computer will break.

A long time ago I was told the "best" way to upgrade a large number of computers was a "doubling" method (geometric progression).

My specific question is:

A) How do I measure my confidence in the upgrade (IE> I want to know (probabilistically) how many computers will break). In the below table I think the confidence level is far too low.
OR
How to I report probability of a failure occurring (which is probably more important, but perhaps is just the inverse of the confidence.

B) Is this actually (provably) efficient?

```
2(n)  Num of upgrades  upgrades   Confidence level
      per round        completed
1     2                2          0.2%
2     4                6          0.6%
4     8                14         1.4%
8     16               30         3.0%
16    32               62         6.2%
32    64               126        12.6%
64    128              254        25.4%
128   256              510        51.0%
256   512              1000       100.0%
```

Further notes.

- The idea is that if a breakage happens, you fix the upgrade, and restart from the beginning. If I had a formula then I could re-calculate based on the reduced total population (as some would already be upgraded
- Not to over complicate, but what if I have, 1% VVIP and 10% VIP, I assume I just leave them until the end of the process to have lowest probability of failure.

Thank you!

Comment: You might be interested in reading about [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) which seems relevant to your problem

Comment: **The idea is that if a breakage happens, you fix the upgrade, and restart from the beginning.... reduced total population (as some would already be upgraded.** Erm...  Do you mean that you do ***not*** re-upgrade the computers on which the faulty upgrade didn't cause the failure immediately???

Comment: @fedja exactly, if they haven't already broken, then rolling back and re-upgrading them would actually increase the risk